# Python - How to print twitter search result

Tags: python, twitter

I'm new to python and I have installed a twitter library from [this link](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) based on the documentation you can use `t.search.tweets(q="#pycon")` to search a keyword on twitter. So I made this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Search a keyword on twitter")
from twitter import *
consumerKey = "xxx"
consumerSecret = "xxx"
accessToken = "xxx"
accessTokenSecret = "xxx"
t = Twitter(
auth=OAuth(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret))
search = raw_input("Insert your keyword here:\n")
t.search.tweets(q=search)
```

but after executing that script it returns empty, it doesn't show any search result on my terminal, did I implement the code wrong or I just don't know how to display the search result ?

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong here, but are you even printing anything out?

why not do:

```
print t.search.tweets(q=search)
```